# Can I change a Twilio Function's behavior (e.g. change a global variable) via the Twilio API?

Tags: twilio

I have written a simple Twilio Function to forward calls to one of my two cell phones numbers A and B.  Occasionally I want to tell the function to stop forward to A and start forwarding to B, or vice versa.

Can I do this programmatically via the Twilio API?  E.g. can environment variables, usually set in [Functions -> Configure](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure), be set via the Twilio API?  Or can I update the Function's code itself via the Twilio API?

If not, must I resort to hosting my code on a 3rd party server, or is there another way to programmatically change what is essentially a global variable for a Twilio Function without manual intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Sadly there is no Functions API to update Functions in this way, yet.

However, may I suggest a workaround for this scenario. You can create two Twilio functions one which forwards to number A and the other which forwards to number B. You can then use the [Incoming Phone Numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) to update your Twilio number's voice URL to point to the Function you need.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks @philnash, that sounds like just the thing!